# foundation menu is not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, zurb-foundation

I'am new to foundation framework and i trying to integrate foundation with CodeIgniter. Everything working but menu portion is not working. it seems the style is not effecting the menu. its been 2-3 days i'am working on this, please help me to solve this.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url().'public/lib/found/'; ?      >
 css/foundation.css" />
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'public/lib/found/'; ?>js/vendor/
 modernizr.js">         </script>
<style>
.columns
{
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>

   <div class="row">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
  <li class="name">
  <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
  </li>
  <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>

   <section class="top-bar-section">
   <!-- Right Nav Section -->
   <ul class="right">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
  <li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Left Nav Section -->
<ul class="left">
  <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
</ul>
 </section>
</nav>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="large-4 columns"><br/><br/></div>
<div class="large-8 columns"><br/><br/></div>
</div>


<script src="<?php echo base_url().'public/lib/found/'; ?>js/vendor/
jquery.js">    </script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'public/lib/found/'; ?>js/
 foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();

  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem. I only added the file which i included in the html page like modernizr.js, foundation.min.js, foundation.css ..etc. But when i added entire foundation folder to my new application its works.